# Calling dealloc in init?

Tags: objective-c, dealloc, init, nsobject

I am writing a framework and I have an object with a custom init method:

```
@implementation OSDatabase
@synthesize database;

// MEM
- (void)dealloc {
  sqlite3_close(database);

  [super dealloc];
}

// INIT
- (id)initWithDatabasePath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    if (!sqlite3_open_v2([path UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL)) {
      error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"OSDatabaseErrorDomain" code:1 userInfo:nil];
      [self dealloc];
      return nil;
    }
  }

  return self;
}

@end
```

Is it safe to call `dealloc` inside of an `init` method if an error occoured? I'm not sure about this and memory management is one of the most important things in my life.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it safe to call dealloc inside of an init method if an error occoured?

No.  send `-release` like you would everywhere else.  Even in `-init` you can't guarantee that the current retain count is 1.

---

Why must you never ever send `-dealloc` except `[super dealloc]` in `-dealloc`?  The reason is that you cannot ever guarantee that something else also has a reference to your object, even in your object's `-init` because the `[super init]` might choose to retain the object.

If the object returned by `[super init]` has a retain count of 1, sending `-release` will have the same effect as sending `-dealloc`.  If it has a retain count of more than 1, something else thinks it owns the object and deallocing it would leave it with an invalid pointer, so `-release` is still the right thing to do.

Also, this:

```
while([self retainCount] != 0){[self release];}
```

would result in an infinite loop and is a terrible idea for a number of reasons.  The retain counts of objects never go down to 0.  `-release` looks something like this:

```
- (id)release
{
    if (retainCount == 1)
    {
        [self dealloc];
    }
    else
    {
        retainCount--;
    }
}
```

so the loop will decrement the retain count to 1 and then continually call dealloc forever or until the heap corruption it has caused leads to a seg fault.

Apart from never reaching zero, the retain may be `UINT_MAX` (for example in string or numeric literals) which colloquially means "this object must never be deallocated".  If the retain count is `UINT_MAX`, `-release` won't decrement it.

Comment: What about `while([self retainCount] != 0){[self release];}`?

Comment: @Koning Baard:  **No!**  That's just as bad.  I'll edit my answer to explain why.

Comment: "Pile of excrement" barely does justice to how wrong that is... :)

Comment: `-retainCount` can return all sorts of things including `UINT_MAX`. Never use it, outside of debugging, and even then, it's not always useful. Especially with ARC.

Comment: @FireLizzard correct, but I would have been happier if you'd just posted the comment and let me amend the answer instead of you rewriting part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Per docs you should never call dealloc directly - only `[super dealloc]` method in your custom dealloc.

I think calling `release` instead should do what expected (at least if you use init method only in standard alloc-init pattern).

Answer (score 0):

As Vladimir stated you should never call `dealloc` directly. when retain count of an object reaches 0, Cocoa automatically calls `dealloc`.