# NSMutableArray memory woes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a result class that has a NSMutableArray within it that is causing me memory leaks. I have been crawling Google to try and find out why but nothing is working.

Can anyone see a memory leak here?

```
@interface Response : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableArray *Items;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *Items;

----

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    self.Items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.Items release], self.Items = nil;
    [Items release], Items = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then its used like this:

```
-(void)Update
{
    Response *resp = [self getResponse];
    foreach(GameObject *o in resp.items){
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
-(Response*)getResponse
{
    Response *result = [[Response alloc] init];
    //Loop through things
    [result.items addObject:o];
    //Finish looping stuff
    return result;
}
```

Im stuck at trying to get this memory leak gone.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray Instance Variable Memory Management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515712/nsmutablearray-instance-variable-memory-management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thew following line is the issue...

```
self.Items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Your items property has a 'retain' attribute which ups the retain count but you also have a retain count of 1 from the alloc. So instead do either of these....

```
self.items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.items = newArray;
[newArray release];
```

Comment: Also in your dealloc EITHER do [items release]; OR self.items = nil; (both do the same). And in your getResponse method you also need to return an autoreleased object as per Pauls suggestion (but this is not the major leak I think you are referring to...)

Comment: Ok, im doing 
`self.Items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];`
and now im just getting one memory leak on 
`Response *result = [[Response alloc] init];`

Comment: yes, when you return the result it should be.... return [result autorelease]; BUT you must make sure that whatever USES this result object retains it if it needs it for any length of time otherwise you will get a bad access.

Comment: @craig how do you know when you get a memory leak? Do you use some kind of tool?

Comment: Hmmm... Im doing what you say but it's crashing next time it tries to release it saying that pointer was not allocated: `[lastResp release];
lastResp = [[self getResponse] retain];`

Comment: I removed `[self.Items release];` and it now works leak free!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that your Response object is what's leaking, as you alloc/init and return it, and dealloc will never be called. You should mark it as autorelease in getResponse()